# Unable to add the git url to connect project in Rstudio with git repository

Tags: r, git, rstudio

Im trying to connect an existing project in R studio with an external git repository. I have installed it and verified that there is communication between this and rstudio. Then I

Execute the Project Options command (from the Project menu)

Choose Version Control options

Change the version control system from (None) to Git

Confirm that you wish to initialize a new Git repository

but I cannot put inside the git url as the relative input (Origin) cannot be clicked. Anybody has the same issue? I am following [this tutorial](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077?version=1.2.1335&mode=desktop).

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear - you already have an R project and also a git repository you'd like to use?  What you're describing from the tutorial is a way to add an existing R project to a new git repository, which will be created.  If you already have an empty repository you'd like to use the easiest thing to do is create a new project from that empty repository and then copy your existing R project to the new project structure.

Comment: yes. when I try to do what you suggest Im facing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275848/error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-no-error-when-trying-to-clone-an-ex